# AngularJS $http.get in IE8 is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I have to develop an angular application in IE8, but I can't reach the server anyway. When I try a $http.get the application is down. The only strange thing is that when I press F12 in the browser (Developer tools) and refresh the web it works perfectly. Does anybody get any answer, please?.

Comment: What happens when you have opened DevTools and go to your page ( not refresh ) ? What are the requests to the server?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using ? Some of them drop IE 8

Comment: Do you try to write something to the javascript console ? IE8 does not create the console object if you don't open the DevTools

Comment: Would be nice if you past some code.

Comment: I use that version https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

Comment: `$http({
        method:'get',
        url:'listdirectaccess',
        cache:false,
        data:"",
        responseType:"json"
  }).success(function(data){
        $scope.directAccess = data.directAcess;
  }).error(function(data){
         
  });`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Angular you're using but as it's said [in the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) :

> Note: AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.

If not can you show us your code. It's a bit hard to help you without any information.

Comment: I use that version github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

Comment: Ok, so you're using a custom build. I'm afraid I can't help you right now. By the way you should mention that fact in your question to have a chance to get a helpful answer. Moreover you should also put your related code in the question to allow people to try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the console.log and $log.debug annotations. When I drop them from the code it works perfectly. I suppose IE8 can't read them without the Developer Tools active and it stops working. 
Thank you for your answers.